# Configuring paths to common parts

Tags: emacs, jedi

If my project has multiple submodules with some common parts that are importing each other. How can point out to jedi where it should pick look for the modules?

Comment: I'm not sure at all how you are using jedi with emacs (there are different variants). The answer is generally that you can use Jedi's environments to work with virtualenvs. There is also a `sys_path` parameter in Jedi that you can use to configure the locations exactly.

Sometimes however it's simply enough to say `pip install -e .` and that is what you really wanted right from the start.

Comment: I am using jedi with emacs-ycm.

Comment: Then please report an issue there or ask there.